# Switch case not working with URLs [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a switch statement:

```
var currentURL = window.location.href;
switch(currentURL)
{
  // Home page
  case "http://localhost/myWebsitePath/":
    alert("Home!");
    break;
  // Blog home page
  case "http://localhost/myWebsitePath/blog/":
    alert("Blog!");
    break;
}
```

When visiting http://localhost/myWebsitePath/, I get the alert. When visiting http://localhost/myWebsitePath/blog/, I don't always get the alert. It seems to sometimes work when clicking a hyperlink from home page. Do I need to escape any special characters to guarantee it works?

Note: both paths have their respective index.html files in the folders

```
console.log(currentURL);
console.log(typeof(currentURL));
```

Produces:

http://localhost/myWebsitePath/blog/
string

Comment: It is probably best if you switch on your console window and look at what `currentURL = window.location.href;` returns. Then make a decision on how to "look" at the result in order to use it for the `switch` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to now work correctly if I use:

```
var currentURL = window.location.href;
currentURL = encodeURIComponent(currentURL);
```

Then switch case as follows:

```
switch(currentURL)
{
  // Home page
  case "http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FmyWebsitePath%2F":
    alert("Home!");
    break;
  // Blog home page
  case "http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FmyWebsitePath%2Fblog%2F":
    alert("Blog!");
    break;
}
```

I used https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ to encode/decode the URLs initially and insert those into my switch cases.